# How to reorder grouped bars in bar chart with R?

Tags: r

Could you please have a look on this code and let me know how to reorder the levels to start with sucrose, p:c, p:c+u, p:c:l+u? and also for the legend to start with the control group?

Here is my code:

```
    Nutrient <- as.factor(c("s", "p:c", "p:c+u", "p:c:l+u"))
    Nutrientlevels<-c("s", "p:c", "p:c+u", "p:c:l+u")
    levels(Nutrient) <- Nutrientlevels
    ggplot(df,aes(x = Nutrient, y = Consumption),levels)+
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Diet), stat = "identity",position = "dodge")+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3")+
    levels(Nutrient)+
    xlab("Nutrient")+
    ylab("Average consumption (mg)")+
    ggtitle("Average daily consumption")+
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = 
    element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = 
    element_line(colour = "black"))+
    guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))+
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = 
    element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_line(colour="black"))+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. It still doesn't order the groups

Comment: How to do it then?

Comment: There are several unrelated mistakes in this code that should be dealt with separately and before this question. For one thing you can't just stick `levels(Nutrient)+` randomly in the `gpplot2` code.

Comment: Please provide some data (some or all of data frame `df`) to [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your code is creating a vector of factors, `Nutrient`, with the correct levels. But then you use a data frame `df`, with a column named `Nutrient`. They are not the same thing unless you assign the vector to the column.

Comment: I can't share the data unfortunately. Is there any way to help without sharing the data?

Comment: They are the same neilfws

Comment: @Sweet Most people have confidential data. However that doesn't mean that you don't have to make reproducible data anyway. This is discussed in the links I shared. It's your job to create fake data that has the same relevant properties as the original data.

Comment: @Hack-R Here is my data frame: df <- read.table(text = " Diet consumption
control s 0.01
                 1:7 s 0.01
                 1:5 s 0.0101
                 control p:c 0.01
                 1:7 p:c 0.01333
                 1:5 p:c 0.1
                  control p:c+u 0.009
                 1:7 p:c+u  0.012
                 1:5 p:c+u  0.001
                 control p:c:l+u 0.007
                 1:7 p:c:l+u 0.005
                 1:5 p:c:l+u 0.003",header = TRUE,sep = "")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work?

Nutrientlevels<- ordered("s", "p:c", "p:c+u", "p:c:l+u")

Comment: I stll get this Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?

Comment: Try removing these three lines instead of the above oneNutrient <- as.factor(c("s", "p:c", "p:c+u", "p:c:l+u"))
    Nutrientlevels<-c("s", "p:c", "p:c+u", "p:c:l+u")
    levels(Nutrient) <- Nutrientlevels

Comment: then how to write the code with ggplot2? Hack-R is correct but don't know how to write it?

Comment: df$Nutrient<- ordered("s", "p:c", "p:c+u", "p:c:l+u") then ggplot(df,aes(x = Nutrient, y = Consumption))+etc

Comment: I got this error non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.ordered", "+.gg") for "+"

Comment: It is hard to help with no reproducible example, but try this df$Nutrient <- as.factor(c("s", "p:c", "p:c+u", "p:c:l+u")) ### ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Nutrient, y=Consumption, fill=Diet)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())

Comment: I did, it cancelled the groups and created only one group!

Comment: I added the data frame above

Comment: try adding next to df$Nutrient <- as.factor(c("s", "p:c", "p:c+u", "p:c:l+u")), the line with df$Diet <- as.factor(c("control",etc...),. It is not clear to me from the df example you typed above what are the levels within diet are

Comment: I have diets: control, 1:7 and 1:5. Each diet includes nutrients: s, p:c, p:c+u, p:c:l+u